# Winsock recv() returning incorrect data

Tags: c++, winsock

My server recv() the packet from the client and must display it.
Problem is its not displaying the correct data

Here is the code:

```
    iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if (iResult > 0) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < iResult; i++ ) {
            printf( "%02x ", buf[i] );
        }
        printf( "\n" );

    // return "cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc"
    // correct return "0A 00 2C 01 29 00 0D 00 B4 01"
```

When a client connects the server displays `cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc` but that's not right
It should be `0A 00 2C 01 29 00 0D 00 B4 01`

---

**UPDATE**

```
    #define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512

    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if (iResult > 0) {
        for ( int i = 0; i < iResult; i++ ) {
            printf( "%02x ", recvbuf[i] );
        }
        printf( "\n" );

    // return "0A 00 2C 01 23 00 0c 00 ffffffB3 01"
    // correct return "0A 00 2C 01 23 00 0c 00 B3 01"
```

now there are extra ffffff on the packet, even though i'm only recv 10 bytes.

Comment: Look at the variables you're using in the `recv` call versus the variables you're using in the `printf` call.

Comment: I updated my question. Thanks for that, very stupid mistake. I didnt notice. :) Anyways, now it returns more data than expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is correct now.  What you're seeing is sign extension when the `char` value you're passing to `printf` is promoted to an `int`.  You can cast the `char` to an `unsigned char` and it should display properly.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < iResult; i++ ) {
    printf( "%02x ", static_cast<unsigned char>( recvbuf[i] ) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it. One last thing sir, how do I send data that is 00 00 on the packet sniffer? is this right? `send( ClientSocket, "", 2, 0);`

Comment: You would send it as any other data, add it to a buffer and send the bytes in the buffer.  What you've shown above is not correct.

Comment: Can you tell me the correct way of doing this? The data is 0x00 0x00. So technically its an empty packet right? Just null null. Its just like a check packet.

Comment: `char buf[2] = {0x00, 0x00}; send( ClientSocket, buf, 2, 0 );`  But, presumably you send other data in your program by constructing a buffer containing some number of bytes and then sending that buffer.  That is how I would do it, the contents of the buffer don't matter, it is all just data whether it is all zeroes or not.